# django - urlpatterns giving 404 error for defined URLs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an application running on django. But I am getting error code 404 for some urls even though these are defined.

```
from .views import check_secret_key                 # a function in views.py
from .swagger_schema import SwaggerSchemaView       # a class inheriting APIView
from .kom.kom_writer import kom_status              # a function
from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/api-docs/', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view()),
    url(r'^nag/secret-key/', check_secret_key),
    url(r'^nag/kom-status/', kom_status),
]
```

API `curl http://localhost:9999/internal/docs/api-docs/` works fine but `curl http://localhost:9999/internal/nag/kom-status/` and `nag/secret-key` fir 404 errror.

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested resource was not found on this server.

I am not sure what is it that I am missing.

**Note**: App was recently updated from DJango 1.8 to 1.11 and djangorestframework 3.2.5 to 3.5.3. Before that it was working fine.

For debugging purpose I am just returning success response right now.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def check_secret_key(request):
    r = HttpResponse("I am good", content_type='text/plain', status=200)
    return r
```

Comment: Can you also post the corresponding views? One reason could be that your view is responding with a 404 code.

Comment: Where does `/internal` come from, because it's not defined in the patterns?

Answer (score 0):

well, your definition should be something like

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'.*docs/api-docs/', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view()),
    url(r'.*nag/secret-key/', check_secret_key),
    url(r'.*nag/kom-status/', kom_status),
]
```

also you need to provide `/internal` url definition.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Application is using two wsgi.py for running django apps.

Both **wsgi.py** files were using

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "it.settings.prod")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "nt.settings.prod")
```

Changing it to

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "it.settings.prod"
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "nt.settings.prod"
```

resolved the problem.

Took reference from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/